# How to query api with filter options

Tags: rest, api

I am trying filter the response city wise. I am not able to understand how to query filter parameters.

I have tried different ways but with no success. This is the response without applying filter. But I want filter it for a particular city.

```
{
  "index_name": "3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69",
  "title": "Real time Air Quality Index from various location",
  "desc": "Real time Air Quality Index from various location",
  "org_type": "Central",
  "org": [
    "Ministry of Environment and Forests",
    "Central Pollution Control Board"
  ],
  "sector": [
    "Industrial Air Pollution"
  ],
  "source": "data.gov.in",
  "catalog_uuid": "a3e7afc6-b799-4ede-b143-8e074b27e0621",
  "visualizable": "1",
  "active": "1",
  "created": 1543320551,
  "updated": 1559683085,
  "created_date": "2018-11-27T17:39:11Z",
  "updated_date": "2019-06-05T02:48:05Z",
  "target_bucket": {
    "index": "air_quality",
    "type": "a3e7afc6-b799-4ede-b143-8e074b27e0621",
    "field": "3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69"
  },
  "field": [
    {
      "id": "id",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "id": "country",
      "name": "country",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "id": "state",
      "name": "state",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "id": "city",
      "name": "city",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "id": "station",
      "name": "station",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "id": "last_update",
      "name": "last_update",
      "type": "date"
    },
    {
      "id": "pollutant_id",
      "name": "pollutant_id",
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    {
      "id": "pollutant_min",
      "name": "pollutant_min",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "id": "pollutant_max",
      "name": "pollutant_max",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "id": "pollutant_avg",
      "name": "pollutant_avg",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "id": "pollutant_unit",
      "name": "pollutant_unit",
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  ],
  "status": "ok",
  "message": "Resource detail",
  "total": 1000,
  "count": 10,
  "limit": "10",
  "offset": "8",
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "13",
      "country": "India",
      "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
      "city": "Rajamahendravaram",
      "station": "Anand Kala Kshetram, Rajamahendravaram - APPCB",
      "last_update": "05-06-2019 02:00:00",
      "pollutant_id": "CO",
      "pollutant_min": "2",
      "pollutant_max": "50",
      "pollutant_avg": "28",
      "pollutant_unit": "NA"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "country": "India",
      "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
      "city": "Rajamahendravaram",
      "station": "Anand Kala Kshetram, Rajamahendravaram - APPCB",
      "last_update": "05-06-2019 02:00:00",
      "pollutant_id": "OZONE",
      "pollutant_min": "37",
      "pollutant_max": "132",
      "pollutant_avg": "71",
      "pollutant_unit": "NA"
    }
    {
      "id": "16",
      "country": "India",
      "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
      "city": "Tirupati",
      "station": "Tirumala, Tirupati - APPCB",
      "last_update": "05-06-2019 02:00:00",
      "pollutant_id": "PM10",
      "pollutant_min": "33",
      "pollutant_max": "72",
      "pollutant_avg": "55",
      "pollutant_unit": "NA"
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.1.0"
}
```

This is only documentation on how to do filtering.

```
properties: OrderedMap { "id": OrderedMap { "type": "integer" }, "date": OrderedMap { "type": "integer" } }
```

How to form request url for filtering the response?

Comment: [Api Webpage Link](https://data.gov.in/resources/real-time-air-quality-index-various-locations/api)

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556943/1844056

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes the documentation is very poor, but still out of many trials I got it work like
 this

`https://api.data.gov.in/resource/3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69?api-key=<your key>&format=json&offset=0&limit=10
&filters[pollutant_id]=NO2`

Comment: How to have multiple queryparams?

Comment: @AnshulBansal check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556943/1844056

Comment: @Raghav7890 @swateek How to filter by date field. I tried `filter[last_update] = 17-05-2020` but its not working

Comment: @ErBharathRam, I haven’t tried it with a date but just a thought, try providing Unix time as value for that last_update.

Comment: @ErBharathRam Are you able to filter based on Date? If yes, can you please give me which method worked for you

Comment: @avatar No I can't able to filter by date