# How to apply filter to get specified data from data.gov.in api?

Tags: java, json, rest, api

I am trying to use data.gov.in api in order to get the air traffic data for my area.

I am using [this](https://data.gov.in/resources/real-time-air-quality-index-various-locations/api#/Resource/get_resource_3b01bcb8_0b14_4abf_b6f2_c1bfd384ba69).

I want to know how to apply the filter and get specified city data (e.g. Noida).

Answer (score 17):

I have used filters in different API like below to pass in querystring,
***&filters[state]=Gujarat&filters[district]=Banaskanth***

It works perfectly.

Example:
https://api.data.gov.in/resource/9ef84268-d588-465a-a308-a864a43d0070?api-key=579b464db66ec23bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX40c1435e88575ea73c1b&format=json&state=Gujarat&offset=0&limit=20&filters[state]=Gujarat&filters[district]=Banaskanth

Comment: How to get a month old data? `filters[date]=01-05-2020` is not working

Comment: @ErBharathRam did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @SuryansuDash not from data.gov.in but I managed to scrape data from [Central Control Room for Air Quality Management](https://app.cpcbccr.com/).You can get source code for it on my github [page](https://github.com/rabhar/Air_pollution_dataset)

Comment: @ErBharathRam Thanks a lot! That was immensely helpful

Comment: @ErBharathRam Just a query, how do I use your scripts to scrape data between 2 specific dates?

Comment: @SuryansuDash change datetime value in aqi_all_Parameters endpoint

Comment: You can also do `sort[price]=asc` (or desc)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this package in Python that handles data.gov.in resources perfectly -
[datagovindia](https://github.com/addypy/datagovindia/)

You can install it with pip :

```sh
pip install datagovindia
```

Here's a solution to your problem. (You can also query for meta-data, and other information on valid fields/ filters, etc.)

Docs are available [here](https://github.com/addypy/datagovindia/).

1. **Import**

```py
from datagovindia import DataGovIndia
```

2. **Initialize**

```py
YOUR_API_KEY = "579b464db66ec23bdd000001cdd3946e44ce4aad7209ff7b23ac571b"

datagovin = DataGovIndia(YOUR_API_KEY)
```

```
# Returns:
# This API key is VALID. You won't need to set it again.
# Latest API-references loaded! You may begin.
```

3. **Find what you need**

```py
datagovin.search_by_title("Air",max_results=2)
```

```
Showing 2 of 1022 results for : `Air`

==================================================================================

Resource-ID:    3b01bcb80b144abfb6f2c1bfd384ba69

Real time Air Quality Index from various location

==================================================================================

Resource-ID:    04ef91fa63844f74b9cc5beb84f53da2

Number of Beneficiaries under Different Schemes of National Scheduled Tribes Finance and Development Corporation from 2016-17 to 2018-19 (From: Ministry of Tribal Affairs)

==================================================================================
```

```json
[{"3b01bcb80b144abfb6f2c1bfd384ba69": "Real time Air Quality Index from various location"},
 {"04ef91fa63844f74b9cc5beb84f53da2": "Number of Beneficiaries under Different Schemes of National Scheduled Tribes Finance and Development Corporation from 2016-17 to 2018-19 (From: Ministry of Tribal Affairs)"}
]
```

3. **Download**

```py
data = datagovin.get_data("3b01bcb80b144abfb6f2c1bfd384ba69",
                          num_results='all',
                           filters={'city':"Noida"})
data.head()
```

|  | id | country | state | city | station | last_update | pollutant_id | pollutant_min | pollutant_max | pollutant_avg | pollutant_unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1514 | India | Uttar_Pradesh | Noida | Sector - 125, Noida - UPPCB | 16-04-2021 12:00:00 | PM2.5 | 62 | 327 | 179 | NA |
| 1 | 1515 | India | Uttar_Pradesh | Noida | Sector - 125, Noida - UPPCB | 16-04-2021 12:00:00 | PM10 | 190 | 431 | 288 | NA |
| 2 | 1516 | India | Uttar_Pradesh | Noida | Sector - 125, Noida - UPPCB | 16-04-2021 12:00:00 | NO2 | 4 | 92 | 14 | NA |
| 3 | 1517 | India | Uttar_Pradesh | Noida | Sector - 125, Noida - UPPCB | 16-04-2021 12:00:00 | SO2 | 2 | 8 | 5 | NA |
| 4 | 1518 | India | Uttar_Pradesh | Noida | Sector - 125, Noida - UPPCB | 16-04-2021 12:00:00 | OZONE | 93 | 241 | 131 | NA |

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found solution yet then check below.
@techkrg is right but you just need to make minor change in that, filters must have correct field names.
e.g. `filters[statename]=Gujarat&filters[districtname]=Banaskanth`